# Change css based on drop down selections value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down

```
<select name="claimsform">
  <option value="lp_claims"> lp_claims</option>
  <option value="gap_claims">gap_claims</option>
  <option value="home_claims">home_claims</option>
</select>
```

**and I want to set the below div's css display to block using jquery depending on what you select on the drop down**

So If i select "home_claims", the div with .home_claims will set the display property to block.

```
<div class="lp_claims">
<p> <strong>LP Claims heading</strong></p>
</div>

<div class="gap_claims">
<p> <strong>GAP Heading</strong></p>
</div>

<div class="home_claims">
<p><strong>Home heading</strong></p>
</div>
```

and my current css is

```
.lp_claims, .gap_claims, .home_claims{ display:none;}
```

Thanks heaps guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('div').hide();
    $('.' + val).css('display', 'block');
}).change();
```

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rCqSS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('select[name=claimsform]').on('change', function(){
var selected = $(this).val();
   $('.'+selected +'').css('display','block');
})
```

See live [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gAKKF/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/sAsA5/

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $doc = $(this);
    var lp_claims = $doc.find('.lp_claims');
    var gap_claims = $doc.find('.gap_claims');
    var home_claims = $doc.find('.home_claims');

    $('#claimsform').change(function() {
        var target = $(this).val();
        if (target === "0") lp_claims.add(gap_claims).add(home_claims).css({ display:"none" });
        if (target === 'lp_claims') lp_claims.css({ display:"block" });
        if (target === 'gap_claims') gap_claims.css({ display:"block" });
        if (target === 'home_claims') home_claims.css({ display:"block" });
    });

});​
```